# Does ETB trigger after legendary rule resolution?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My friend is building a commander deck and wants to confirm if his latest combo is correct.

Currently, there is a [Reflections of Littjara](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Reflections%20of%20Littjara) on the battlefield, and the dragon creature type has been named. If I cast [Miirym, Sentinel Wyrm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Miirym%2C%20Sentinel%20Wyrm), the following events occur:

1. The Reflections of Littjara trigger, creating a legendary copy of Miirym on the stack.
2. The legendary copy of Miirym enters the battlefield.
3. The real Miirym enters the battlefield. I must sacrifice one Miirym since both are legendary.

My question is: Does the Miirym token still trigger from the enter-the-battlefield ability of the real Miirym? If it does, does this mean a non-legendary token of Miirym is created and enters the battlefield?

Comment: First thing to note: a permanent being moved to the graveyard via the legend rule is _not_ sacrificing it. Probably doesn't matter here but has important interactions with lots of other cards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, the ability triggers and you create a non-legendary copy of Miirym.**

Focusing just on the resolution of the original Miirym spell, the sequence of events goes like this:

1. The original Miirym spell resolves. Miirym enters the battlefield, and the ability on the existing token copy of Miirym triggers.
2. State-based actions are checked, and you must choose to put one of the two Miiryms into your graveyard.
3. The triggered ability is put on the stack.
4. After all players pass priority, the triggered ability resolves, creating a non-legendary copy of Miirym.